# Query regarding T-SQL programming

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently in an interview i came across a question. Here i am posting the same, please help me with the query. I have a table with only one column. In that column the values are following. All i have to do is, replace the nulls below the value A with A, replace the null below the value B with B similarly replace the nulls below the value C with C. I do not know the approach to solve the problem. I tried using sub-queries and string functions but nothing worked out. Thanks in advance.

```
A
NULL
NULL
B
NULL
NULL
C
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: `replace the nulls below the value A with A` ... this is a meaningless statement unless a column is specified which provides an _ordering_ giving the table you showed us above.  There is no internal order in a SQL Server table.

Comment: i had given the existing data in the table, consider that as the existing data and kindly answer the question

Comment: Can we assume that there is some primary key column present?  If so, please assign values to this column.

Comment: What Tim said is true,you should have asked the interviewer ,on what  basis,you are saying `replace the null below the value B with B `

Comment: There is nothing on the column, if you assume there is primary key on the column, then it wont allow NULLs no. We now have only one column which is like i mentioned above and there is nothing defined on that column

Comment: Thanks Tim for you immediate response, i will now put the words exactly asked by the interviewer (telephonic interview). He has given me the above mentioned data and asked the question i had mentioned earlier.  That is it, i did not asked him any further questions. Further he asked me , atleast to tell the appraoch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok lets assume the table name is `Test` and **lets assume the records will always be returned in the order above (which in practice the will not always as mentioned by many comments)** now lets also assume the column name is `a`

so you could create the table with the following query

```
CREATE TABLE Test(a CHAR(1))
GO
```

Then you would `INSERT` records described above like this

```
INSERT INTO Test(a)
VALUES 
('A')
,(NULL)
,(NULL)
,('B')
,(NULL)
,(NULL)
,('C')
,(NULL)
,(NULL)
GO
```

Now since you said this was a `T-SQL` question we can use a query to solve the problem like this below

```
DECLARE @val CHAR(1), @last_val CHAR(1);

DECLARE cur CURSOR
  FOR SELECT a FROM Test;
OPEN cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @val

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
  IF @val IS NULL BEGIN
    UPDATE Test SET a = @last_val
    WHERE CURRENT OF cur; 
  END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @last_val = @val
  END 
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @val
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

So then when you run

```
SELECT a FROM Test
```

your result will look like this

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

Comment: `FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @val` may not be consistent

Comment: yes I'm aware that records are not stored in order that is why I mentioned the fact in my answer, and said lets assume they will be in order for this. But I totally agree the premise of the question is poor but still this likely along the lines of the desired answer

Comment: + 1, I was thinking with cursor, and stuck with fetching the same row, and I was going to use the `Row_Number` for this, but this is first time for knowing `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Very much TheGameiswar. is there any other way to achieve the same without using the cursor